# Couple of questions on Custom Adapter class

Tags: android

```
    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView item1;
        public TextView item2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.document_item_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.big);
            holder.item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.small);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        final DocumentResponse custom = entries.get(position);
        if (custom != null) {
            holder.item1.setText(custom.getCreateByFullName());
            holder.item2.setText(custom.getTitle());
        }
        return v;
    }
```

1. Can anyone explain me on the parameters of the overridded method. [`getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`]. I need to know what does each argument do?.
2. I have a static class ViewHolder holding my view components, then why do i create a nerw instance `holder`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3864111/1168654

Answer (score 0):

For the getView method :

- position is the index in the list, you will use it to get the current object from the data source
- convertView is a View... which is a view returned by the getView method for another position, so you don't have to inflate the view for each row, you can reuse one.
- parent is probably the container, but I never used it.